# ошибка в Android-приложении с передачей по Bluetooth

Tags: android, bluetooth

Пытаюсь написать программку для Android, позволяющую по нажатию кнопки передавать значения по блютуз, код вроде без ошибок, приложение в режиме отладка запускается, но при нажатии на кнопку останавливается...

Пожалуйста, помогите найти ошибку в коде.

```
package com.example.klic;

import android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.util.UUID;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    private static final String TAG = "KKDSO";

    Button button1, button2;
    private OutputStream outStream = null;

    private static final UUID MY_UUID = UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB");

    // MAC-адрес Bluetooth модуля
    private static String address = "98:d3:31:30:1b:04";  //Вместо “00:00” Нужно нудет ввести MAC нашего bluetooth

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1); //Добавляем сюда имена наших кнопок
        button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);

          final int REQUEST_ENABLE_BT = 1;
         BluetoothAdapter btAdapter = null;
         BluetoothSocket btSocket = null;
         OutputStream outStream = null;

        btAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();


        button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()  //Если будет нажата кнопка 1 то
        {
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                sendData("1");         // Посылаем цифру 1 по bluetooth
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Включаем LED", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();  //выводим на устройстве сообщение
            }
        });

        button2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                sendData("0"); // Посылаем цифру 1 по bluetooth
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Выключаем LED", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }



    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }


    private void sendData(String message) {
        byte[] msgBuffer = message.getBytes();

        Log.d(TAG, "...Посылаем данные: " + message + "...");

        try {

            outStream.write(msgBuffer);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            String msg = "In onResume() and an exception occurred during write: " + e.getMessage();
            if (address.equals("00:00:00:00:00:00"))
                msg = msg + ".\n\nВ переменной address у вас прописан 00:00:00:00:00:00, вам необходимо прописать реальный MAC-адрес Bluetooth модуля";
            msg = msg +  ".\n\nПроверьте поддержку SPP UUID: " + MY_UUID.toString() + " на Bluetooth модуле, к которому вы подключаетесь.\n\n";


        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Права включены?

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" /> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
```

Comment: Что то я отстал от жизни с этим вопросом, по этому уже не могу проверить:( Ну может кто то так же озадачится таким вопросом:)